# How to enable covariance in a class with a generic type?

Tags: flutter, dart

`Pet<String> pet = Dog<String>();` gives me an invalid_assignment error.

```
class Pet<T> {
  T name;
}

class Dog<T> extends Pet {}

class Cat<T> extends Pet {}

main() {
  Pet<String> pet = Dog<String>();
  List<Pet> pets = List<Dog>();
}
```

The `List<Pet> pets = List<Dog>();` works

How do I allow the `Pet<String> pet = Dog<String>();` line to run without an error?  I think this is covariance and I think in this article it explains how to do it in c#.  Does Dart allow you to allow covariance somehow?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces

Comment: `class Dog<T> extends Pet<T> {}`

Comment: thank you, that does indeed work! I have a more complicated scenario that I was trying to simplify which still doesn't work when I do this but I'll look at why and update. Thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the same generic to both class and the type that it extends.

```
class Pet<T> {}
class Dog<T> extends Pet<T> {}
```

this then allows

```
Pet<String> pet = Dog<String>();
```

because `Dog` of generic type `String` extends `Pet` of generic type `String`.

**You wrote** (missing the generic type from Pet)

```
class Dog<T> extends Pet {}
```

so
instantiating `Dog()` would the same as

```
Dog<String> extending Pet<dynamic>
```

`dynamic` because that is the default type for generics if one is not specified; downcasting it seems is not a valid and supported type of covariance in Dart

Comment: Suggest to have some explanations

Comment: Good point :-) It made me actually think about the answer too!